# Wordpress Modulle Help

Tags: php, wordpress

I created a wordpress module, with a single function that outputs some dynamic data. I would users to be able to call the plugin from pages. I've seen this b4 w/ the contact plugin, you create a page and just [[contact-form]] on the page. How can I do this?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are called *shortcodes* in WP:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API